# CSS: Designing to Print Dynamic Documents from Browser

Tags: css

No coding issues this time; just a request for a link or 2 to guide me to the right tutorial(s).

I want to render HTML in such a way that it is all formatted and ready to print standard-sized pages, such as letter-sized (8.5" * 11") documents.  I would like the browser's built-in "print" feature to handle the printing.

The documents I have in mind will have dynamic content - like line items in an invoice.  You don't know how many items the customer is buying, and for that reason, you don't know how many pages there will be.  I can generate the HTML, but I figure there must be some kind of CSS schema that handles all the page formatting, etc.

What is/are some simple, non-proprietary approaches to do this? I am just seeing something I've never heard of (CSS @page), but I know so little on the topic that I want to be sure I am on the right track and it is still all current stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS media queries** will enable you to create styles that are specifically for **print media**.  This way you can have the page print however you like.

Here are some good resources:

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp
- http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_for_print_tutorial